# Does Raspberry Pi 2/3 supports PNaCl?

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, chromium, chrome-os

I have Raspbian and Chrome-OS in different SD cards.

My initial tries shows that both official repos hosts a version of Chromium, but they had NaCl disabled explicitly.

Will it work if I compile Chromium from source?

Comment: well, why don't you compile it and tell us? :)

Comment: There were issues with PNaCl (or was it just NaCl) a couple of years ago with the toolchain. I assume they've been solved by now.